# Displaying a Collection in a PropertyGrid Control

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I have an array of objects containing pairs of string labels and values, how would I put them all in a single property grid?

```
    public class stringVariable {
        public String name;
        public String defaultValue;
        public String value;
    };
    public List<stringVariable> variables = new List<stringVariable>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an array of objects to a property grid is pretty well covered in a number of tutorials. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/customizingcollectiondata.aspx) should be what you're looking for.

Comment: please explain your answer

Answer (score 3):

Its not entirely straight forward, but possible. You need to have a class that implements ICustomTypeDescriptor, which will tell you what properties to display, etc. There are a few implementations out there, I was using this one:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/bending_property.aspx