# Do I have to use a CollectionBase for a PropertyGrid list?

Tags: c#, list, propertygrid

I am coding a C# forms application where I am using a class with a `PropertyGrid`. I am needing to have `Lists` that have nested `Lists`, and some `Lists` have other objects that need to be selected.

My question is this: Do I have to use a `CollectionBase` for collections? All of the tutorials I have seen online use a `CollectionBase`, however I have tried a simple test application with a `List`, and the `List` works correctly so far.

I am asking this so that I do not get in depth into my code, and realize that a `CollectionBase` is needed for certain `PropertyGrid` actions.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying a Collection in a PropertyGrid Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638184/displaying-a-collection-in-a-propertygrid-control)

Comment: I am asking whether I NEED to use a CollectionBase, not how to use a CollectionBase. The above duplicate links to an old resource, and is one of the many resources I have had a look at.

Comment: The linked resources makes it pretty clear that the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` interface doesn't care about what the underlying type is, as long as it fulfills it's contract to the interface. There is no way for the interface to know anything at all about the runtime type of the implementing class.

Comment: I can decorate the class with the required attributes for the properties, without using a ICustomTypeDescriptor and the list works correctly. Hence, I am asking about whether the CollectionBase is needed.